# SET XML EXPLICIT QUERY TO VARIABLE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to generate the following XML string in SQL and assign it to a variable.

```
<List>
   <V Value="TESt">
       <Target a="10" b="11"/>
   </V>
   <T Value="TESt1">
       <Target a="100" b="101"/>
   </V>
</List>
```

So, I wrote the following SQL code:

```
;WITH XML_CTE AS
(
SELECT 
    1 AS TAG,
    NULL AS Parent,
    UT.title AS [v!1!Value],
    null AS [Target!2!a],
    null AS [Target!2!b]
FROM 
(
    select  
        10 AS A,
        11 AS B,
        'TESt' as title
    union
        select  
        100 AS a,
        101 AS b,
        'TESt1' as title
)UT
UNION ALL
SELECT
    2,
    1,
    UT.title AS Value,
    ut.a,
    ut.b
FROM
(
    select  
        10 AS a,
        11 AS b,
        'TESt' as title
    union
        select  
        100 AS a,
        101 AS b,
        'TESt1' as title
)ut
)
SELECT * FROM XML_CTE 
ORDER BY 
    [V!1!Value], 
[Target!2!a]
FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('List')
```

But how do I assign it to a xml(or nvarchar) variable? Because of the "UNION ALL", I had to wrap it in CTE, but having it in a CTE, I am unable to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You could alter the `SELECT * FROM XML_CTE...` statement to the following

```
SELECT @MyVariable = 
    (SELECT * FROM XML_CTE 
    ORDER BY 
        [V!1!Value], 
    [Target!2!a]
    FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('List')
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an initial set of data something like:

```
Col1     A     B
------------------
TESt     10    11
TESt1   100   101
```

then I would recommend using `FOR XML PATH,ROOT` rather than the old, legacy `EXPLICIT` mode (which is really complicated and convoluted)

```
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH XML_CTE(Col1, A, B) AS
(
  SELECT 
     'TESt', 10, 11
  UNION
  SELECT    
    'TESt1', 100, 101
)
SELECT @Result =
   (SELECT
       Col1 AS '@Value',
       A AS 'Target/@a',
       B AS 'Target/@b'
    FROM XML_CTE 
    FOR XML PATH('V'), ROOT('List')
   )
```

Gives me an output of:

```
<List>
  <V Value="TESt">
    <Target a="10" b="11" />
  </V>
  <V Value="TESt1">
    <Target a="100" b="101" />
  </V>
</List>
```

as you asked for.

Comment: I need to pass that xml string to another Stored Procedure.
How do I set that XML to a nvarchar variable?

Comment: @PertinentObserver: added another sub-select after the CTE to store the result into a `nvarchar(max)` variable. But since this is really **pure** XML - why aren't you just using the `XML` datatype?? Would make a **lot** more sense than `nvarchar(max)` ...